# how springboot project to set request argument

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

My controller accepts an object to save it, and the object has a field named addTime,and i have to set this field by myself ,how can i do to let this operation automatically by springboot features。

```
@PostMapping("/HotelVersionDistribute/apply")
    @Override
    public Result<Boolean> apply(@RequestBody HotelVersionDistribute entity) {
        // i dont want to do it,but i have no idea 
        entity.setAddTime(LocalDateTime.now());

        HotelClientVersion hotelClientVersion = hotelClientVersionMapper.selectById(entity.getVersionId());
        if(hotelClientVersion == null){
            log.warn("version_id={},not exit", entity.getVersionId());
            return Result.error(Result.CODE_REASOURCE_NOT_EXIST, "版本未找到");
        }

        saveApply(entity, hotelClientVersion);

        return Result.success(true);
    }
```

Comment: What are you using for persistence? You could have a field that is updated when you write to your data store.

Comment: Why don't you just set the value on your entity since you're the value will be always now?

Answer (score 1):

In general such columns ( createdBy , createdDate , updatedBy ,updatedDate )like addTime are called audit columns.

Spring provides Auditing support for Spring Data / Spring Data JPA . Since the question does not mention the same and assuming you are using one of those , please read through and implement your requirement.

From the documentation : [Auditing](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#auditing)

> Spring Data provides sophisticated support to transparently keep track
> of who created or changed an entity and when the change happened. To
> benefit from that functionality, you have to equip your entity classes
> with auditing metadata that can be defined either using annotations or
> by implementing an interface

Answer (score 0):

Two ways:

1. Direct set value in class:

```java
public class HotelVersionDistribute {
    private LocalDateTime addTime = LocalDateTime.now();
    ...
}
```

2. Use MySQL's default value mechanism, and set column `updatable` to `false`

```java
public class HotelVersionDistribute {
    @Column(insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private LocalDateTime addTime;
    ...
}
```